# Flattening a list of lists in racket

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket, fold

I'm working on an assignment in Racket (Intermediate Student with lambda) and I'm trying to make a helper function which flattens a list of lists. I'm not allowed to use recursion, nor can I use apply.

I tried using foldr and append, but append isn't allowed as well. So, I tried making my own append function but struggled to do so without recursion. Any help or insight would be appreciated

```
(define (flatten list)
       (foldr append '() lol))
```

Comment: Can you use loops? Any recursive algorithm can be converted to iterative.

Comment: No, loops are not allowed. I have to use abstract list functions for this particular assignment.

Comment: This sounds like a puzzle, not a real programming task. What's the point of all these constraints?

Comment: In particular, you have this tagged `functional-programming`, and recursion is a common feature of FP.

Comment: You can't have loops in scheme/racket without ultimately using recursion. Even `map`, `foldl`, `foldr` etc. use recursion.

Comment: Try implementing `append` in terms of `foldr`. As a warmup, implement `map` and `filter` in terms of `foldr`.

Comment: sounds like a specific exercise to think in terms for `foldl` and `foldr`. otherwise i'd say anyone teaching not to use recursion in scheme should find a different language to teach

Answer (score 4):

Given that so much is disallowed, the point of the exercise may be to appreciate the power of that which is allowed. In this case, that seems to include `foldr`.

Let's start with an example list.

```
(define nums '((1 2) (3) (4 5 6)))
```

We want the result of `(flatten nums)` to be `(1 2 3 4 5 6)`. Let's try working backwards, assuming we can use `foldr`. Folding is all about interspersing an operator between values. `cons` is an operator that builds lists. Let's try that.

```
> (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))))))
(list 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

That works. Now we just need to figure out how to call `foldr` in a way that replicates this sequence of applications of `cons` to items in the input list.

We can use `foldr` to automate the first two calls to `cons`.

```
> (foldr cons (cons 3 (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '())))) '(1 2))
(list 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Repeating the process...

```
(foldr cons
       (foldr cons
              (cons 4 (cons 5 (cons 6 '()))) '(3)) '(1 2))
```

```
(foldr cons
       (foldr cons
              (foldr cons
                     '() '(4 5 6)) '(3)) '(1 2))
```

If we stare at this long enough, we might realize this is just another `foldr` where the operator is

```
(lambda (ls xs)
  (foldr cons xs ls))
```

Making that substitution...

```
(foldr
 (lambda (ls xs)
   (foldr cons xs ls))
 '() '((1 2) (3) (4 5 6)))
```

And that's flatten!

```
(define (flatten lss)
  (foldr
   (lambda (ls xs)
     (foldr cons xs ls))
   '() lss))
```

```
> (flatten nums)
(list 1 2 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: This is probably what is expected for the assignment, but it is worth mention that this definition for `flatten` does not behave as many typical `flatten`-like procedures; e.g., Racket's `flatten` can handle lists with top-level elements and nested elements, where this definition would fail for both cases. A better name for this might be something like `de-nest` to emphasize that it is just removing one level of depth from the list expression.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm not sure how to achieve arbitrary-depth flattening within the posed constraints. Using a fixed-point combinator would work but is surely not expected (or allowed?) here.

Comment: Simply, `if (pair? ls) (foldr ... ls) (cons ls xs)` , no?

Comment: @WillNess Wouldn't the `...` have to contain a copy of the `if` expression, resulting in an infinite nesting?

Comment: Yes, you're right. my bad.

Comment: OTOH, we could write out some N-layered `if`, and have a function capable of handling tree-like lists *up to* the nesting depth of N, a.o.t. your version handling only 1-deep nesting.

Comment: @WillNess That's correct. In practice, an input tree will not be infinitely deep. If we know the maximum tree depth, we can construct a procedural nesting deep enough to handle it. This insight is the basis of [SICP's derivation of the Y combinator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAlR3cezPJg&list=PLE18841CABEA24090&t=3350s).

Answer (score 1):

Function calls are allowed. Thus we can call a function we will arrange to receive as an argument.

This is not recursion, but rather this *emulates* recursion by passing a lambda function as an argument to *self*, so *self* is able to call the copy of *self*, again with *self* as an argument, so the copy is able to call another copy of *self* again, as and if needed:

```
(define (flatten xs)
  ((lambda (g) (g g xs))    ; top call: (self self xs)
   (lambda (g xs)           ; g: a function to call
     (cond
       ((empty? xs)             ; no more input: 
         xs)                          ; STOP
       ((empty? (car xs))       ; car is empty list:
        (g g (cdr xs)))               ; go on with the rest
       ((not (cons? (car xs)))  ; atomic leaf:
        (cons (car xs)                ; get it
              (g g (cdr xs))))        ; and go on with the rest
       (else                    ; car is a pair:
        (g g (cons (caar xs)          ; rotate the tree right once,
                   (cons (cdar xs)    ; to bring the leftmost atom
                         (cdr xs)))))))))   ; closer to the top
```

At each non-trivial step we rotate the input tree to the right, so that the leftmost leaf is eventually brought up to the top, for an easy detachment. Each rotation preserves the order of the tree's fringe elements as seen "from below", traversed left-to-right, which *is* what `flatten` produces. This is the [essence](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+gopher) of the ["gopher" trick](http://www.dreamsongs.com/10ideas.html) by John McCarthy, used in his implementation of `same-fringe`.

Testing,

```
(flatten '(((1) 2) (3 (4) 5)))

=> (list 1 2 3 4 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

see how it looks with tail recursion:

```
(define (custom-flatten lst)
  (define (core lst acc)
    (cond ((null? lst)
           acc)
          ((list? (first lst))
           (core (rest lst) (core (first lst) acc)))
          (else
           (core (rest lst) (cons (first lst) acc)))))
  (reverse (core lst '())))


(define (main-test)
  (let ((test-value '(1 2 ((b b) a c d) (s (f ((f)))))))
    (or (equal? (custom-flatten test-value)
                (flatten test-value))
        'main-test-fails)))

;> (main-test)
; #t
```

Comment: Did you not see "I'm not allowed to use recursion"?

Comment: @molbdnilo oh, I'm really translate it as "I am not understand how to use recursion". Sorry, I am not an english.